# xcode build error: " Conflicting types for 'uint64' " makes no sense to me

Tags: c, xcode

I am not a regular programmer, but of necessity.  I am using the tiff-4.0.3 as part of an upgrade to an xcode program I had running under MacOS 10.5

When I build, I get the error message:

> Conflicting types for 'uint64'

The line that is flagged is located in tiff.h and reads:

```
typedef TIFF_UINT64_T  uint64;
```

The only other line I can find in the project with TIFF_UINT64_T is located in tiffconf.h and reads:

```
/* Unsigned 64-bit type */
#define TIFF_UINT64_T unsigned long
```

In any case, the error makes no sense to me.  There are a large number of similar definitions, none of which flag the same error.  Is it possible that the library libtiff.la has a conflicting definition?  Is there any way to check this?  I cannot get NM or otool to reveal what is in the library.

Other than that, I am at a loss on where to look.  I have done the configure/make/install several times in case it is some omission in the process, but to no avail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
typedef TIFF_UINT64_T  uint64;
```

This defines a new type called `uint64`. However, it is very likely that another library you are using defines `uint64`, since it is quite a common type name.

Try asking Xcode to show you the definition of `uint64` after commenting out an `#include` for `tiff.h`, to see where else it is defined.

The types likely conflict because `uint64` is usually defined as `unsigned long long` (or some variation on that), and this line defines `uint64` as `unsigned long`. (Whether that is correct or not depends on the compiler settings, but it is not the same as `unsigned long long`).

Answer (score 0):

To me this looks like a bad coding practice in both `libtiff` and Apple libraries which define this type.

The type `uint64` is defined in `/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Headers/cssmconfig.h` for example.

Probably the best way to fix this is to patch `libtiff` to use `uint64_t` instead of `unsigned long`.

(I submitted a bug report to http://bugzilla.maptools.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2464.)